# Get Unique values from Feed URL using javascript Fetch functions

Tags: javascript

I trying to extract data from feed URL, which returns dynamic 25000 records, using Fetch function in JavaScript,  I tried passing ?Field name as options to get the records , but it does not help.

below is sample code:

```
var FeedURL="RSSFEEDURL"
fetch('FeedURL')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

As I need bind these values to Dropdown, how best we can filter the Feed URL.

Thanks in Advances.

Comment: If you wan to reduce the number of items or fields you are getting from the server, there is no way to give you a general answer. If they support filtering, this depends on who wrote the feed endpoint. Consult the documentation of who wrote the feed, or contact them.

Comment: Can you pls provide a sample response which you get from FeedUrl. You can use Postman to get the response.